# How to determine whether a return char pointer needs to be free in C standard library functions?

Tags: c, pointers, free, c-standard-library

I've little experience in `C` program developing. As I described in the title, how to determine whether a return char pointer needs to be free in C standard library functions? For examples, do I need to free the return pointer of function `getenv` in `stdlib.h` and `strstr` in string.h? I can't find any description in the document.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good design and reading the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv

> Modifying the string returned by getenv invokes undefined behavior.

So you shouldn't touch that one.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr

> Return value: Pointer to the first character of the found substring in str

This returns a pointer to a character within the input c-string. So it's a pointer to memory that already existed, not a newly allocated string, and you shouldn't `free` it.

p.s. Though it doesn't change the answer, I took the perspective of the C++ tag of the question. For C language documentation see the manual pages or, for this website, http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv and http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr (that have essentially the same content as the above)

Answer (score 7):

Each function should note that in its manual page.

E.g. `getenv()` says nothing about deleting, and it's really not necessary (or would be wrong). `vasprintf()`, on the other hand, clearly states that the pointer returned must be `free()`'d.

Answer (score 4):

In gnu/linux enter [man strstr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr)  (or search it with your preferred web search engine).

[Manual page for `getenv`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv) also states:

> The getenv() function searches the environment list to find the environment variable name, and returns a pointer to the corresponding value string.

The design idea here and in *C* in general is not to make any necessary copies, but to point to already existing data for performance reasons.

A counter example is [`strdup`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup), which makes a copy of a string using internally `malloc`, and has to be `free()`d.

Answer (score 2):

Always render unto `free()` what `malloc()` and family rendered unto thee.

The family are `calloc()` and `realloc()`.

Most other standard library functions don't return newly allocated memory and don't need to be `free()`d. `strdup()` (if provided) is an exception rather than the rule.

Functions like `fopen()` return a pointer that does need to be surrendered but by `fclose()` not `free()`.

But unfortunately the real answer is 'check the documentation and know your libraries'.

A fact of C coding is you are almost entirely responsible for resource management including knowing exactly what resources to surrender and when.

This is the power and the curse of C. Hurray you're in control! Sh*t! You're in control.

Answer (score 1):

For example, looking at [The Man of getenv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) you can read:

> **Notes**
>
> [...]
>   As typically implemented, getenv() returns a pointer to a string within the environment list. **The caller must take care not to modify this string** , since that would change the environment of the process[...]

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

And

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The getenv() function searches the environment list to find the
>   environment variable name, and **returns a pointer to the >corresponding
>          value string**.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

In other words, you mustn't free that pointer because is a pointer to a string in process environment, not a string allocated for your job.

Comment: I think you are missing an 'n' in your answer!

Comment: @Rene Got it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Properly designed libraries *never* return pointers that you have to manually `free()`. If they use dynamic memory or other resources that need clean-up, they will have a function for that purpose - a destructor if you will, that you must call manually.